# Derivation of Steepest Descent Direction used in Line Search Methods

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, euclidean-geometry, descent

In the numerical optimization text I am reading, the Steepest Descent Direction was derived by considering

$$
\min_{||p||_2\leq 1}  p^T\nabla f(x_k)
$$

This resulted in

$$
p_k=-\frac{\nabla f(x_k)}{||\nabla f(x_k)||_2}
$$
I am wondering if there is any significance of the Euclidean norm being used. I.E. would a different norm, such as the 1-norm or maximum(infinity)-norm result in a different steepest descent direction vector?

Comment: If you choose a different norm for the '$p$' ball you will get a descent direction but it will differ from the gradient, in general. There are various 'variable metric' methods that you could look at. Consider Newton's method on a convex function.